# Configuring SQL Server database transaction logs truncation regularly?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, azure-vm

How can I configure SQL Server 2014, to allow truncating the logs by itself so that it doesn't fill up my database drive?

I need some help as I'm not a DBA myself and this SQL Server is installed within Azure VM backed up with Azure backup which does not truncate log files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need point in time recovery in your database?

Comment: Are you taking log backups to use Point in Time Recovery?  If not, the DB could be set to 'simple' mode so the log auto truncates.

Comment: Azure Backup should perform the log backups.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/faq-backup-sql-server

Comment: If you don't need Point In Time recovery then just switch to Simple Recovery Model

Comment: No, I do not need Point in Time. So I assume I can just set it to Simple recovery mode so the tx logs can be under the control ?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, based on the link you've provided, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/faq-backup-sql-server#can-i-use-azure-backup-for-iaas-vm-as-well-as-sql-server-on-the-same-machine- "copy-only full backup on the VM to not truncate the logs."

Comment: Thank you @DavidBrowne-Microsoft for your guidance :-)